# IPv6-only client connecting to Docker container on Rancher using an Application Load Balancer?

Tags: docker, ipv6, rancher

We are developing an application for a platform that uses only IPv6 addresses on their client.  We have built out our infrastructure using Rancher Server and Rancher hosts for the application containers.

Rancher does not support IPv6, so to allow the IPv6-only client to be able to connect to the application, I have put an Application Load Balancer (ALB) that supports IPv6 in front of the Rancher load balancer, which uses `haproxy`.

In Route53, my A and AAAA entries point to the application load balancer which is then forwarding traffic to the haproxy loadb alancer in Rancher which then distributes traffic to the application.

When we test the client, we are getting an error which states that the host is unreachable via IPv6.   However if the ALB (application load balancer) is accessible via IPv6, it can forward to an IPv4-only host when it receives a connection from an IPv6-only client.

Comment: Kubernetes IPv6 support is coming. [See this tracker issue.](https://github.com/kubernetes/features/issues/563) There is already partial support.

Comment: I actually solved the issue - I realized that in my terraform security group script, I was not adding IPV6 cidr blocks so therefore ipv6 traffic was not permitted at all. I updated my security group settings via Terraform and voila - this works as expected.   So anyone who is looking for ipv6 support for your applications using Rancher on AWS, you can accomplish this using a dualstack application loadbalancer (ALB).  Make sure your VPC is configured with ipv6 so this works.

Answer (score 1):

I actually solved the issue - I realized that in my terraform security group script, I was not adding IPV6 cidr blocks so therefore ipv6 traffic was not permitted at all to any of my instances. I updated my security group settings via Terraform and voila - this works as expected. So anyone who is looking for ipv6 support for your applications using Rancher on AWS, you can accomplish this using a dualstack application loadbalancer (ALB). Make sure your VPC is configured with ipv6 so this works.

Make sure your security groups allow for ipv6 traffic by configuring an ipv6 cidr block on the respective ports.